# Replacing for..in with lodash version

Tags: javascript, loops, lodash

How to replace `for .. in` and `hasOwnProperty` with a lodash function?

```
function Foo() {
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;
}

Foo.prototype.c = 3;

var foo = new Foo();
for(var key in foo){
    if(foo.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

This should print independently of order **1** and **2**. It will skip the **3**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `forEach` method:

```
_.forEach(foo, function(value, key){
    console.log(key, value);
});
```